# javascript design pattern not returning intellisense for some objects

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, intellisense

I'm messing about with a javascript pattern that will allow me to namespace my code and to define shortcuts internally out of the global scope to reduce the amount of typing I will have to do.

Things like $ instead of jQuery or $messageType instead of messages.messageType.

Whilst the pattern seems to be working nicely I have lost certain intellisense functionality now in visual studio 2010.

e.g. My test function below will alert "success" but my intellisense doesn't enumerate through the $messageType object properties.

Since productivity is the key this is a big issue for me.

Is there something i've missed that the javascript gurus can pick up on?

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamessouth/AYR6H/1/) to play about with.

```
; (function (window) {

    // Define a local copy of myObject
    var myObject = function () {
        // The myObject object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new myObject.fn.init();
    },

    // Shortcuts.
    // A central reference to the root messages object
    $messages = null,

    // A central reference to the root messages.messageType object
    $messageType = null;

    myObject.fn = myObject.prototype = {
        init: function () {
            // Initialise the object shortcuts.
            $messages = this.messages;
            $messageType = this.messages.messageType;
        }
    };

    // Give the init function the myObject prototype for later instantiation
    myObject.fn.init.prototype = myObject.fn;

    myObject.fn.messages = {
        /// <summary>
        /// Provides means to provide feedback message to the client.
        /// </summary>
        messageType: {
            information: "information",
            error: "error",
            success: "success"
        }
    };

    myObject.fn.tester = function () {
        alert($messageType.success);
    };

    // Expose myObject to the global object
    window.myObject = window.$m = myObject();
} (window));

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $m.tester();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh.... I forgot to return the object in my init function!!

```
myObject.fn = myObject.prototype = {
    init: function () {
        // Initialise the object shortcuts.
        $messages = this.messages;
        $messageType = this.messages.messageType;
        // It took jslint ans a cup of coffee to figure this out :)
        return this;
    }
};
```